# setting virtualhost on xampp

Tags: xampp, virtualhost

I'm using two xampp applications. First xampp has default setting such port apache on 80. Second xampp, i use for a project learning that apache on 9999. I wanna make an virtualhost on second xampp. I did set on

Hosts file

```
127.0.0.1 localhost 
127.0.0.1 helloword.com
```

Httpd.conf

```
Listen 9999
```

Httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<Virtualhost *:9999>
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/project/public" 
   ServerName helloword.com
</Virtualhost>
```

It is where file index.html on public folder. But, when i browse http://helloword.com, it failed to view index. Index can browsed when i type `http://localhost:9999/`

Where should i change that setting?

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment the below line in your httpd.conf.

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Comment: @VinaL: ... did you restart Apache after making that change?

Comment: Done. I also tried to change settings related with it. It has no worked yet. Does anyone know where the fault is?